# IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL at .iso boot | Problems with Windows 10 virtualisation

Tags: linux, windows-10, virtual-machine, bsod

Since my gaming hardware supports IOMMU, I decided to migrate the machine to Linux.

**The setup:**

- AMD FX-8350
- 8 GB 1600
- Asus Sabertooth 990FX R1.0
- ATI HD 5450 (for base system)
- nvidia GTX970 (for VM)

I installed a clean Void Linux and set up IOMMU and fixed my IVRS table. Afterwards, I bound my nVidia GTX 970 to the `vfio-pci` kernel module. Then I set up `libvirtd` daemon with its dependencies, where I had to add `virtlogd` and `dbus` daemon by hand. Then I installed virt-manager and set up a new VM based on the recommendations from the answers.

**Update (overcome the BSOD)**

after trying the prebuild arch OVMF images with the same results i started to change ALL the options. *u know just in case.*

One of the first things i tried was switching from `host-passthrough`/`Copy host CPU configuration` in CPU to `Hypervisor Default`. Now the installer starts without any issues. So the IRQL error is caused by the CPU passtrough!

Problem: I will have performance impacts if i emulate a CPU instead of just handing it over. So the goal will be to get `host-passthrough`/`Copy host CPU configuration` to work...

**The original issue:**

When i try to boot from a current and tested Win10.iso it gives me the BSOD with `IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL`.

So how can I fix the BSOD?

I see that the error is related to memory allocation, but I have no idea what to change to make it work.

I already had the VM up and running (so it is possible to get around that error), except for the error 43 thing from nVidia, but then i realized that my base system was corrupted, so I decided to do a clean reinstallation, which worked perfectly until the first VM boot up.

Heres the current XML. Its lacking the vfio-drivers.iso and the Bootdrive, because the problem is that the Win10.iso won't boot.

```xml
<domain type='kvm'>
  <name>win10</name>
  <uuid>6f957f60-c90c-4d33-8821-01348fa531a9</uuid>
  <memory unit='KiB'>6291456</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>6291456</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static'>8</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-q35-2.12'>hvm</type>
    <loader readonly='yes' type='pflash'>/usr/share/edk2.git/ovmf-x64/OVMF_CODE-pure-efi.fd</loader>
    <nvram>/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/nvram/win10_VARS.fd</nvram>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <hyperv>
      <relaxed state='on'/>
      <vapic state='on'/>
      <spinlocks state='on' retries='8191'/>
    </hyperv>
    <vmport state='off'/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode='host-passthrough' check='none'/>
  <clock offset='localtime'>
    <timer name='rtc' tickpolicy='catchup'/>
    <timer name='pit' tickpolicy='delay'/>
    <timer name='hpet' present='no'/>
    <timer name='hypervclock' present='yes'/>
  </clock>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
  <pm>
    <suspend-to-mem enabled='no'/>
    <suspend-to-disk enabled='no'/>
  </pm>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source file='/home/pitch/Downloads/Win10_1803_EnglishInternational_x64.iso'/>
      <target dev='sdb' bus='sata'/>
      <readonly/>
      <boot order='1'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='1'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-ehci1'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x1d' function='0x7'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci1'>
      <master startport='0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x1d' function='0x0' multifunction='on'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci2'>
      <master startport='2'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x1d' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci3'>
      <master startport='4'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x1d' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='sata' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x1f' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='0' model='pcie-root'/>
    <controller type='pci' index='1' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='1' port='0x10'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0' multifunction='on'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='2' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='2' port='0x11'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='3' model='pcie-to-pci-bridge'>
      <model name='pcie-pci-bridge'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x01' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='4' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='4' port='0x12'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='5' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='5' port='0x13'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x3'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='6' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='6' port='0x14'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x4'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='virtio-serial' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x04' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <interface type='network'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:36:19:70'/>
      <source network='default'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x02' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'/>
    <input type='keyboard' bus='ps2'/>
    <sound model='ich6'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x03' slot='0x01' function='0x0'/>
    </sound>
    <hostdev mode='subsystem' type='usb' managed='yes'>
      <source>
        <vendor id='0x046d'/>
        <product id='0xc069'/>
      </source>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='1'/>
    </hostdev>
    <hostdev mode='subsystem' type='usb' managed='yes'>
      <source>
        <vendor id='0x046d'/>
        <product id='0xc316'/>
      </source>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='2'/>
    </hostdev>
    <hostdev mode='subsystem' type='pci' managed='yes'>
      <source>
        <address domain='0x0000' bus='0x04' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
      </source>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x06' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </hostdev>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x05' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
</domain>
```

---

**OLD XMLs**

This was my original libvirt XML:

```xml
<domain type='kvm'>
  <name>win10</name>
  <uuid>502f32c7-01fc-4690-98b7-85c1c82e392b</uuid>
  <memory unit='KiB'>4194304</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>4194304</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static'>4</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-i440fx-2.12'>hvm</type>
    <loader readonly='yes' type='pflash'>/usr/share/edk2.git/ovmf-x64/OVMF_CODE-pure-efi.fd</loader>
    <nvram>/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/nvram/win10_VARS.fd</nvram>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <hyperv>
      <relaxed state='on'/>
      <vapic state='on'/>
      <spinlocks state='on' retries='8191'/>
    </hyperv>
    <vmport state='off'/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode='host-passthrough' check='none'/>
  <clock offset='localtime'>
    <timer name='rtc' tickpolicy='catchup'/>
    <timer name='pit' tickpolicy='delay'/>
    <timer name='hpet' present='no'/>
    <timer name='hypervclock' present='yes'/>
  </clock>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
  <pm>
    <suspend-to-mem enabled='no'/>
    <suspend-to-disk enabled='no'/>
  </pm>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='qcow2'/>
      <source file='/var/lib/libvirt/images/win10.qcow2'/>
      <target dev='sdb' bus='sata'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='1'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source file='/home/pitch/Downloads/Win10_1803_EnglishInternational_x64.iso'/>
      <target dev='hda' bus='ide'/>
      <readonly/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='file' device='floppy'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source file='/home/pitch/Downloads/virtio-win-0.1.149.iso'/>
      <target dev='fda' bus='fdc'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-ehci1'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x7'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci1'>
      <master startport='0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0' multifunction='on'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci2'>
      <master startport='2'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci3'>
      <master startport='4'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='0' model='pci-root'/>
    <controller type='fdc' index='0'/>
    <controller type='ide' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='virtio-serial' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='scsi' index='0' model='virtio-scsi'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x09' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='sata' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x07' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <interface type='network'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:04:2a:7a'/>
      <source network='default'/>
      <model type='rtl8139'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <serial type='pty'>
      <target type='isa-serial' port='0'>
        <model name='isa-serial'/>
      </target>
    </serial>
    <console type='pty'>
      <target type='serial' port='0'/>
    </console>
    <channel type='spicevmc'>
      <target type='virtio' name='com.redhat.spice.0'/>
      <address type='virtio-serial' controller='0' bus='0' port='1'/>
    </channel>
    <input type='tablet' bus='usb'>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='1'/>
    </input>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'/>
    <input type='keyboard' bus='ps2'/>
    <graphics type='spice' autoport='yes'>
      <listen type='address'/>
      <image compression='off'/>
    </graphics>
    <sound model='ich6'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
    </sound>
    <video>
      <model type='qxl' ram='65536' vram='65536' vgamem='16384' heads='1' primary='yes'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
    </video>
    <redirdev bus='usb' type='spicevmc'>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='2'/>
    </redirdev>
    <redirdev bus='usb' type='spicevmc'>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='3'/>
    </redirdev>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x08' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
</domain>
```

Just to test, I tried stripping the VM configuration.  Here's the XML dump:

```xml
<domain type='kvm'>
  <name>win10</name>
  <uuid>502f32c7-01fc-4690-98b7-85c1c82e392b</uuid>
  <memory unit='KiB'>6291456</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>5242880</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static'>8</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-i440fx-2.12'>hvm</type>
    <loader readonly='yes' type='pflash'>/usr/share/edk2.git/ovmf-x64/OVMF_CODE-pure-efi.fd</loader>
    <nvram>/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/nvram/win10_VARS.fd</nvram>
    <bootmenu enable='no'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <hyperv>
      <relaxed state='on'/>
      <vapic state='on'/>
      <spinlocks state='on' retries='8191'/>
    </hyperv>
    <vmport state='off'/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode='host-passthrough' check='partial'/>
  <clock offset='localtime'>
    <timer name='rtc' tickpolicy='catchup'/>
    <timer name='pit' tickpolicy='delay'/>
    <timer name='hpet' present='no'/>
    <timer name='hypervclock' present='yes'/>
  </clock>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
  <pm>
    <suspend-to-mem enabled='no'/>
    <suspend-to-disk enabled='no'/>
  </pm>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source file='/home/pitch/Downloads/Win10_1803_EnglishInternational_x64.iso'/>
      <target dev='sda' bus='scsi'/>
      <readonly/>
      <boot order='1'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-ehci1'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x7'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci1'>
      <master startport='0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0' multifunction='on'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci2'>
      <master startport='2'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci3'>
      <master startport='4'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='0' model='pci-root'/>
    <controller type='scsi' index='0' model='virtio-scsi'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x09' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='virtio-serial' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'/>
    <input type='keyboard' bus='ps2'/>
    <hostdev mode='subsystem' type='pci' managed='yes'>
      <source>
        <address domain='0x0000' bus='0x04' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
      </source>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
    </hostdev>
    <hostdev mode='subsystem' type='usb' managed='yes'>
      <source>
        <vendor id='0x046d'/>
        <product id='0xc069'/>
      </source>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='1'/>
    </hostdev>
    <hostdev mode='subsystem' type='usb' managed='yes'>
      <source>
        <vendor id='0x046d'/>
        <product id='0xc316'/>
      </source>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='2'/>
    </hostdev>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x08' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
</domain>
```

Comment: `IRQF_LESS_OR_EQUAL` is (one of) Windows's obfuscated way of saying it hit a null pointer dereference.  It's almost always a driver issue, which in turn means either bad hardware of poorly written drivers (or the hardware changed in a way that Windows did not expect).

Comment: It doesn't have to be a "null pointer". It can be a reference to pageable memory from IRQL 2 or above. Such bugs can lurk undetected for a long time until the memory in question just happens to be paged out one day. (e.g. someone allocated paged pool instead of nonpaged.) But yes, it's almost always a driver issue. If the OP can post their minidump file to a public file sharing site, we may be able to figure out which driver is the culprit.

Answer (score 6):

## Updated Answer

*It sounds like you were able to reinstall Windows, but the first boot blue-screened.  This updated answer addresses that.*

Windows is fragile when it comes to hardware changes, virtualised or bare metal.

If you changed something in your libvirt domain XML after installation, the `IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL` blue screen of death could easily happen.

It's especially hard to figure out what caused the blue screen if you do not remember what you changed.  For example, if I installed Windows on the `scsi` (`virtio-scsi`) disk bus and then changed the disk bus to `virtio` (`virtio-blk`), I'll get this far before the guest crashes with no details:

[image: UEFI TianoCore Windows boot]

The easiest way to resolve this is to configure the libvirt domain XML how you want it beforehand and then reinstall Windows for that hardware.

A harder way would be to start up the Windows install ISO, add virtio-win drivers with `DISM`, and hope that one of them fixes the BSOD.  You would have to adapt the instructions from [this Super User answer](https://superuser.com/a/1200899/83694).  It's an annoying process with no guarantee of success.

<sup><sub>(And in the case of changing the boot disk bus after installation, it does not appear to be possible for Windows 10, [as I found out](https://superuser.com/questions/1057959/windows-10-in-kvm-change-boot-disk-to-virtio#comment1489202_1057959).)</sub></sup>

So spare yourself the headache of troubleshooting and reinstall Windows once more.

Here's how I customised my libvirt domain XML for Windows:

- The installed boot disk uses `scsi` as its disk bus with `discard='unmap'` in the `<driver>` for TRIM support.
- The installer CD/ISO drive uses the `sata` bus so that the Windows installer can boot.
- The [virtio-win](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/quick-docs/en-US/creating-windows-virtual-machines-using-virtio-drivers.html) drivers ISO drive also uses `sata` so that the Windows installer can read it.
- I use `q35` as the `machine` attribute of the `<type>` under `<os>` instead of `pc` (`i440fx`) for [better support of PCIe passthrough](https://wiki.qemu.org/Features/Q35) because i440FX only supports PCI.  Note that `q35` requires a different set of `<controller>` elements.  You can set this in `virt-manager` if you delete (undefine) your current guest, create a new one, check "Customize configuration before install", and then change the chipset from `i440FX` to `Q35`.
- The network adapter model is `virtio` for best performance.
- The video model is QXL for a better-performing display.

In the Windows installer, install all the compatible drivers from the virtio-win ISO before completing the disk partitioning step:

[image: Windows installer: Select the driver to install]

Hopefully after the reinstall, you should no longer be getting the blue screen of death.

---

## Old Answer

*This answer went on the assumption that you were trying to reinstall Windows.*

According to the libvirt XML file you provided, you are not booting from the ISO file (`cdrom`).  You seem to be booting directly from your virtual machine image, which likely contains Windows installed on different hardware and is thus incompatible with the virtualised hardware.

You can boot from `cdrom` by adding

```xml
    <boot dev='cdrom'/>
```

right above

```xml
    <boot dev='hd'/>
```

and then starting the virtual machine normally.  Note that the Windows boot disk may give you a time-limited prompt to press any key to start the installer.

---

Alternatively, you can enable booting from `cdrom` through virt-manager like so:

[image: Boot Options in virt-manager]

Comment: yeah i just choose it from the bootmenu of OVMF but ill give it a try anyway.

Comment: no progressit wont boot at all this way just asking for the keypress to boot from CD then the tianocore logo, repeat. after a while it drops me to the EFI-shell

Comment: @pitchzer0: I can reproduce that on virt-manager.  The trick is to do a "Force Reset", quickly click in the middle of the black screen, and then spam keys on the keyboard.

Comment: to achieve what exactly? i am trying different storage bus settings now and even removed the "hdd" from the device list to exclude it as a troublemaker.

Comment: @pitchzer0: To boot from the ISO

Comment: Thats not the issue. i am a noob regarding VMs but i know the basic concept of boot. :-)

Comment: @pitchzer0: I now understand that you are troubleshooting a BSOD at first boot.  I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @Deltkin You still missed the fact, that there was no installation in the first place. the IRQL BSOD is shown at every boot of the Win10.iso drive, ill rewrite my answer a lil...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80862/discussion-between-deltik-and-pitchzer0).

Answer (score 1):

```
  <cpu mode='host-passthrough' check='none'/>
```

I soved this issue on my side with setting the CPU-Type from "host-passthrough/host-model" to a pre-defined "Opteron G4"-template - I have an Threadripper-Processor. Windows can't handle too much possibilities.

Hopefully this is helpful.

**Edit 25.03.2019**

Further Details on my solution:
I've encountered the same issues as above, which I could "solve" by setting the CPU-Type in Virt-Manager (not editing the XML-File) to an "Opteron G4".

I solved the Windows Issue with that but was still fighting with other issues and GPU-Passthrough didn't work properly. I could start the VM but the GPU was not correctly listed in the VM and couldn't install the driver, the GPU was not detected.

I found this tutorial: https://heiko-sieger.info/running-windows-10-on-linux-using-kvm-with-vga-passthrough/ which from my pov covers a lot of topics on GPU-Passthrough. Especially on the "Troubleshooting" section, whih at the end helped me to solve my problem.

Due the fact that I was using an X399 Taichi Motherboard in combination with Threadripper CPU which at that time weren't capable to work, I encountered several problems including the one with the CPU-host-passthrough which actually didn't really make sense to me because I already have successfully done this on other hardware.

For me at the end updating the BIOS did the trick. There was an update for especially those functionalities.

After that everything just worked like a charm.

From my experience, it needs:

-Hardware needs to be ready + look for BIOS update which are related.

-Settings on the Motherboard like SVM/xVTd, IOMMU, ACS and other Motherboard-related options needs to be activated.

-Using the newest packages provides probably the best experience.

-It needs two GPU's. The first one should be either onboard or dedicated. Otherwise it probably won't really work smoothly...

-nVidia doesn't like it, AMD is a friend of linux.

Hope this helps. For futher question, don't hesitate.

Comment: Maybe it’s obvious to somebody, but it’s not to me. What’s the relationship between your code block (```check='none'```) and your paragraph text (“… setting the CPU-Type from "host-passthrough/host-model" to a pre-defined "Opteron G4"-template”)?